# How to specify 'schema sync only' as system variables in mariadb columnstore

Tags: configuration, mariadb, columnstore

Bonjour à tous,
We currently use mariadb columnstore in 2 dev environments, Linux and Windows to avoid to force all members of our team to reinstall their desktop.

Few days ago, after merged a branch which used columnstore instead of simple Mariadb, we have met an issue with windows env to create tables that we managed to solve by added COMMENT='schema sync only' after the definition of the engine.

The issue is that Windows is not our final targeted deployment environment and this command is not needed in Linux. So, we want to set it as a system variable only in case of Windows environment but we currently do not manage to do it.

to complet the scope, we use the docker image mariadb/columnstore:1.2.5 which should normally be the last one at this moment, and Changelog.db to deploy our db schema.

Thanks to let me know if you have the answer.

Best regards,
Mathieu

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after surfing a whole day on the web for the following original issues which lead us to the previous question, I fell on a link in github which solved our issue. I share it because this issue is only for windows so not necessary really common.
Error Code: 1815. Internal error: Calpont system tables can only be created with 'SCHEMA SYNC ONLY'

--> https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-columnstore-docker/issues/7

the main idea is to use named volume instead of -v path to persiste the columnstore schema